# How to import flat file by skipping header and footer using Sql Server query

Tags: sql-server, csv, flat-file

I want to import flat file using SQL Server query. Flat file is PIPE delimited with one HEADER row and one FOOTER row.

Flat file sample is as follows,

```
H|201501204|01
1|abc|123
2|efg|456
4|hij|789
T|03
```

in above file **H and T** are fixed defining **HEADER and FOOTER** respectively, '201501204' will be the date, '01'will be the flat file number, '03'will be count of data rows in flat file.

I have tried using Bulk Insert but I am losing one Data Row while importing Flat file.
I am using FIRSTROW=2 and LASTROW=2651, number of data rows in my Flat file are 2650 but after importing i am getting only 2649 rows in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the BULK INSERT statement (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), the option you want is FIRSTROW and set that to 2 (the 2nd row in the file). You can also use LASTROW.

Alternatively load the data into a staging table first - single column and then split it in SQL Server having excluded the H and T by WHERE LEFT( input_line, 1 ) not in ( 'H', 'T' )

Comment: how can i count last row number in a flat file without loading it.

Comment: I have tried Bulk insert but i am losing one data row while importing flat file.

Comment: On your BULK INSERT statement (please post) if you are using FIRSTROW = 2 then you will indeed miss the first row which I believe is what you wanted.

Comment: I am using FIRSTROW=2 and LASTROW=2651, number of data rows in my Flat file are 2650 but after importing i am getting only 2649 rows in table.